# How to print four digit numbers in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a shell script that does this:

Takes `input 4` and prints:

```
0000
0001
0002
```

until

```
9999
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `seq` to generate a series of numbers between a start and stop value with a `printf` format string:

```
width=4
start=1
stop=9999
seq -f "%0${width}g" "$start" "$stop"
0001
0002
0003
0004
...
9997
9998
9999
```

If your OS is one of the super rare ones that does not include `seq` (which is not a POSIX requirement) you can use `awk` which is a POSIX requirement:

```
awk -v w="$width" -v start="$start" -v stop="$stop" 'BEGIN{
     for(i=start;i<=stop;i++) printf("%0*d\n", w, i)}'
```

Or use `bc` to replace `seq` and `xargs` to call `printf` in pipe:

```
echo "for (i = $start; i <= $stop; i+=1) i" | bc -l | xargs printf "%0${width}d\n"
```

Or, Bash or similar only, a C style loop:

```
for (( i=${start}; i<=${stop}; i++ )); do
    printf "%0*d\n" "$width" "$i"
done
```

Or, any POSIX shell, a while loop:

```
cnt="$start"
while [ "$cnt" -le "$stop" ]; do
    printf "%0*d\n" "$width" "$cnt"
    let cnt++
done
```

Your *superpower* here is `printf` with the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `for` loop to iterate over desired range.
2. Use `printf` to format the number of digits you want to print.

The solution for your question is

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the number of digits: " num_digits
START=0
STOP=9999
for((i=${START};i<=${STOP};i++))
do
    printf '%0'${num_digits}'d\n' $i
done
```

Save this file and execute it. When prompted for number of digits, enter the number of digits you want to the output to be formatted.

Comment: `printf "%0${num_digits}d\n"` maybe better? Also, CAPITALIZED variables are [by convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) for system and environment in Bash or shell scripts